# Killing a process and PID recycling

Tags: php, process, pid

I have a web based PHP application that triggers a background processes on the server.  The process is started on via the web UI that keeps itself updated via a database table and a timed AJAX update.

I wan't to give the uses a way to cancel the process.  So I have the process save its PID in a file.  If the file exists the UI assumes the process is running and offers the ability to abort.  It will then attempt to kill the process.

My concern is that in the case of a fatal error in the background process, the PID file may not get removed.  The UI will still assume the process is running and if the user kills that PID is there not a chance the PID stored in the file might have been recycled by the system and there for a chance that the user can kill a random (possibly important) process on the server.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Russell

Comment: why don't you parse output of `ps` command instead of creating files? (Assuming that your server is not based on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [posix_kill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-kill.php). Also, see [proc_terminate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php).